read_html() in R not returning table from website HTML code
I am trying to extract the Team Statistics and Team Analytics (5-on-5) table from https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2025.html .
When I use the read_html() function from the rvest package in R, the code does not include these two tables. It does include the standings table at the top of the page but not the other two.
I used read_html("https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2025.html") and the html_text() output of the code does not include the tables in question. As well as using html_elements() with the xpath of the tables and there being no result.

This is similar to this question: Webscraping with rvest : https://www.sports-reference.com.
The tables are stored in the comments of the web page.  There is a RSelenium solution or you could parse out the comments and process them with just rvest.
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2025.html"

page<-read_html(url)  # read html
page %>% html_table()  # the first 2 tables 

commentedNodes<-page %>%                   
   html_nodes('div.table_wrapper') %>%  # select node with comment
   html_nodes(xpath = 'comment()')    # select comments within node

#there are multiple  nodes containing comments
#chose the 2 via trial and error
additionaltables <- lapply(commentedNodes, function(node) {
   node %>%
      html_text() %>%             # return contents as text
      read_html() %>%             # parse text as html
      html_table()
})
additionaltables[[2]][[1]]

